# Brokerbin authentication

Tags: c#, encryption, soap, blowfish

We are trying to authentificate ourself in brokerbin service. They provided us with encryption key and login/pass. The documentation says login and password should be encrypted with BLOWFISH_ECB. But the service continues to response "Failed authentification".

We are using BlowFishCS library.
Here the sample code we are using.

```
var client = new BrokerBinService.HandleSearchPortClient();

string reqUsername = "my_login";
string reqPassword = "my_pass";
string key = "provided_enc_key";

var algo = new BlowFishCS.BlowFish(key);

var encrytedUSerName = algo.Encrypt_ECB(reqUsername);
var encryptedPassword = algo.Encrypt_ECB(reqPassword);

var authResponce = client.Authenticate(encrytedUSerName, encryptedPassword, null);
```

Here is the PHP code sample from brokerbin documentation. From that sample we could see that there are different keys for login and password, but tech support says we should use the same key for both.

```
$username = '';
$password = '';
$uname_key = 'code';
$pword_key = '';

//INITIALIZE THE MCYPT EXTENTION
$td = mcrypt_module_open (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, "", MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, "");
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ($td), MCRYPT_RAND);

// ENCRYPT USERNAME
mcrypt_generic_init ($td, $uname_key, $iv);
$username_enc = base64_encode(mcrypt_generic($td, $username));
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

// ENCRYPT PASSWORD
mcrypt_generic_init ($td, $pword_key, $iv);
$password_enc = base64_encode(mcrypt_generic($td, $password));
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);

// CLOSE THE MCRYPT EXTENTION
mcrypt_module_close($td);

// START THE SOAP CLIENT
$client = new SoapClient('http://soap.brokerbin.com/brokerbin_search/search.wsdl');

// DO NOT SET RESULT_TYPE TO XML HERE (AUTHENTICATE)...
$opts=array('checkout_seconds'=>86400);
$uid = $client->Authenticate($username_enc,$password_enc,$opts);
```

I wonder if there are people who has successful experience with brokerbin integration and could shed a light on our problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Php strings use single-byte-per-character strings. In your C# sample, you use the UTF-16 default for strings. This will yield a different output when encrypted through blowfish.

Answer (score 1):

Php strings use single-byte-per-character strings. In your C# sample, you use the UTF-16 default for strings. This will yield a different output when encrypted through blowfish.

You'll want to run your C# strings through

```
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
```

before feeding them to the Blowfish encryption functions.

Comment: Thank tou, Paul. It's a good point and we have already tried it. The problem remains. We have also run their php code and it didn't help.